# Why do these sums return the same result when the results should be different?

Tags: summation, series-expansion

```
Sum[1, {k, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> Dirichlet]
```

gives -1/2, which is right.

```
Sum[1, {k, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> Dirichlet]
```

also gives -1/2 which is wrong. The correct result should be 1/2.

This comes from the property of linearity that the summation method should exhibit. Particularly, in the case of Zeta regularization,

$\qquad \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^a=\zeta(-a, 0)$

and

$\qquad \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^a=\zeta(-a, 1)$

where $\zeta(x,y)$ is the Hurwitz Zeta function.

The Dirichlet regilarization is a generalization of Zeta regularization, so it should be consistent with it. Is this a bug?

Comment: I do not understand why these `Sum`s should give different answers. Both have an infinite sequence of 1's as argument, so I expect the same answer (but I do not know what Dirichlet regularization is).

Comment: @Fred Simons because they start at different indexes. Both stability and linearity require them to give different results. $\sum_0^\infty 1=1+\sum_1^\infty 1$. One can see the first one as the quantity of natural numbers while the second as the quantity of non-negative integers.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag for your own questions, as explained in the tag description. This is regardless of whether you are convinced that it is a bug.  Also, what exactly is the question?  Bug reports should go to Wolfram if you want the problem to be fixed.  I really hate to vote to close questions like this, especially from high rep users, but the fact is that this is not a question at all, and unless it is made into a plausible question, it has no place on SE.

Comment: @Anixx I gave the last close-vote and it was a hard decision because I think it is a valid question to ask what is happening here. I looked into it and I don't see a way how the community can debug why this is happening. This question should be answered by support@wolfram.com and if this is a bug or an oversight, please edit this question and add our bug-header.

Comment: @halirutan what do you mean by bug-header?

Comment: For issues that are **confirmed** bugs (confirmed by Wolfram support), we have (a) a special text we place at the top of the question like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175917/187) and (b) we tag the questions with the `bugs` tag.